# Custom expression in JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I have an Entity with a String field (storing JSON), and need to compare value from its database column with another value. Problem is that type of this database column is TEXT, but in fact it contains JSON. So, is there a way to write something like this? I.e. I need to compare my value with some field of JSON from TEXT column.

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("json_column").customExpressionn(new Expression{
   Object handle(Object data){
    return ((Object)data).get("json_field")
}
}), value)
```

Comment: use CAST? use FUNCTION?

Comment: @NeilStockton, do you mean call sql function, that parses JSON and return my field?  I hoped to find some CriteriaAPI solution.

Comment: @NeilStockton, my entity? How can it help? My entity just have `String` field, which contains JSON.

Comment: I've no idea what you're trying to achieve then. You have a String field storing a String value, stored in a TEXT column, and want to compare it to some value. You don't need any custom handler for that, just do "equal()". If you are instead wanting to compare some part of the text string ... then you give an example of the text string that is in the datastore and what part you want to compare with

Comment: @NeilStockton, here is an example of this string: "{field1: \"value\",field2: \"value2\"}". I need to compare some my string with value of field2.

Comment: String fields have use of functions like SUBSTRING, LOCATE in JPQL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119023/discussion-between-ivan-timoshin-and-neil-stockton).

Answer (score 7):

**Assuming, you have a MySQL server with version > 5.7.x**

I just had the same issue. I wanted to find all entities of a class that had a JSON field value inside a JSON object column.

The solution that worked for me was something along the lines (sorry typing from a phone)

```
(root, query, builder)->{
    return builder.equal(
        builder.function("JSON_EXTRACT", String.class, root.get("myEntityJsonAttribute"), builder.literal("$.json.path.to.json.field")),
        "searchedValueInJsonFieldOfJsonAttribute"
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi , Found your post quite useful , can you please help me building the following query with criteria , like you shared above?   SELECT * FROM `audit_log` WHERE 
    JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(myEntityJsonAttribute 'one', 
        "$.json.path.to.json.field");